# Choosing betwen browser cache vs local cache for my application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

I want to my service response in my application? Last few days i am checking for the best solution and i have too many options to choose.

> - Browser Cache
> - HTML5 Local Cache
> - MVC4 Cache
> - Jquery Cache.

My application is built on MVC/Ajax/Bootstrap. Mainly i am using jquery to fetch my data from the services.

Comment: Please take a look at [ask] in the [help]. This question is far too broad, and asks for opinions, which are both off topic.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help to rephrase your actual choices:

- Client-side cache
- Server-side cache
- Local Storage cache

None of these are mutually exclusive. You can use one or all three. In fact, it's extremely typical to employ both client-side and server-side cache. Local Storage cache is kind of new concept. It's not a true cache, per se, but some developers are beginning to toy around with it for things like caching ajax-request scripts, using AMD-style inclusion of JavaScript.

If you're really script heavy and especially if you're already targeting mobile or modern browsers, then you might want to look into some of the Local Storage caching experiments out there. However, most of these are in fact, just that: experiments, and may not be ready for production use. Otherwise, just focus on server-side and client-caching.

Server-side caching involves the server storing data in memory for use in other requests. This might be an actual data structure or a string consisting of some pre-rendered HTML. Caching server-side allows your server to work a little less hard at the cost of additional memory requirements. It works really well with data that is static. For example, if you have site navigation that is pulled from a database, but doesn't change all that often, it makes a lot of sense to cache the rendered site navigation HTML, so that the server can simply use this for other requests instead of having to query the database and rebuild all the HTML each time.

Client-side cache involves the client (most typically, a web browser), storing the assets received by from the server and using these to render the view for the user, without having to issue another request to the server. Things like images, JS, CSS, etc. are all prime candidates for client-side caching, since these typically don't change from page to page. As a result, once the browser's cache is "primed" from the first request to a site, it typically only needs to request just the page HTML from the server. It can then use the supporting assets from the cache to fully render the page. Even the HTML can be cached, though, so if you have a certain page that is mostly static, you can set Cache-Control or Expires headers that suggest that the browser may choose to cache the page if it chooses to.